# Controlling more than one properties for custom component on scenebuilder

Tags: javafx, custom-controls, scenebuilder

I cannot see the old values of a property of custom component on Scene Builder. 
I want to get the old value of "Speed Unit Type" to change the Min/Max values accordingly.

Maybe I can use static Min / Max values and bind these to "Speed Unit Type". But just wonderwhether it is possible to use old values at design tima on SB.

```
public static enum SpeedUnitType {KILO_METERS_PER_HOUR,METERS_PER_SECOND,DATA_MILES_PER_HOUR}

public static final int SPEED_MAX_DEFAULT_VALUE =  1000; 
public static final int SPEED_MAX_LIMIT_VALUE = 999;
public static final double SPEED_MIN_LIMIT_VALUE = -100;
private final IntegerProperty   minValue    = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
private final IntegerProperty   maxValue    = new SimpleIntegerProperty(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
private final IntegerProperty   value       = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

private SpeedUnitType                      _speedUnit = SpeedUnitType.KILO_METERS_PER_HOUR;     
private ObjectProperty<SpeedUnitType>       speedUnitTypeProperty  ;

public final SpeedUnitType getSpeedUnitType() {
    return null == speedUnitTypeProperty ? _speedUnit : speedUnitTypeProperty.get();
}

public final void setSpeedUnitType(final SpeedUnitType UNIT) {
    if (null == speedUnitTypeProperty) {
        _speedUnit = UNIT;
    } else {
        speedUnitTypeProperty.set(UNIT);
    }
}

public final ObjectProperty<SpeedUnitType> speedUnitTypeProperty() {
    if (null == speedUnitTypeProperty) {
        speedUnitTypeProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "speedUnitTypeProperty", _speedUnit);
    }
    return speedUnitTypeProperty;
}

public Speed() {
    this.construct();
}

public void setMinValue(int min){ this.minValue.set(min); }
public int getMinValue() { return this.minValue.get(); }
public IntegerProperty minValueProperty() { return this.minValue;}
public void setMaxValue(int max) { this.maxValue.set(max);}
public int getMaxValue(){ return this.maxValue.get();}
public IntegerProperty maxValueProperty() { return this.maxValue; }
public final int getValue() { return value.get(); }
public final void setValue(final int VALUE) { value.set(VALUE);}
public final IntegerProperty valueProperty() {return value;}

private void construct()
{       
    this.maxValueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("maxValueProperty --> The value was changed from " + oldValue.toString() + " to " + newValue.toString());

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            setText("ERROR");
        }
    });

    speedUnitTypeProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        this.convertSpeedUnit(oldValue, newValue);
    });

    // this.maxValueProperty().bind(Bindings.add(10, this.minValueProperty())); test to bind property min to property max


}
```

// ******************** Utility Methods ***********************************

```
public void convertSpeedUnit(SpeedUnitType oldValue, SpeedUnitType newValue)
{   
    if (oldValue == null)
        return;
    if (oldValue == newValue){}
    else{
        switch (oldValue){

        case KILO_METERS_PER_HOUR:
            System.out.println("convertSpeedUnit::formerUnit - KILO_METERS_PER_HOUR");
            switch (newValue){
            case METERS_PER_SECOND:
                System.out.println("convertSpeedUnit::currentUnit - METERS_PER_SECOND");
                setMinValue(10);
                setMaxValue(20);
                break;
            case DATA_MILES_PER_HOUR:
                System.out.println("convertSpeedUnit::currentUnit - DATA_MILES_PER_HOUR");
                setMinValue(11);
                setMaxValue(21);
                break; 
            }
            break;
        case METERS_PER_SECOND:
            System.out.println("convertSpeedUnit::formerUnit - METERS_PER_SECOND");
            switch (newValue){
            case KILO_METERS_PER_HOUR:
                System.out.println("convertSpeedUnit::currentUnit - KILO_METERS_PER_HOUR");
                setMinValue(12);
                setMaxValue(22);
                break;
            case DATA_MILES_PER_HOUR:
                System.out.println("convertSpeedUnit::currentUnit - DATA_MILES_PER_HOUR");
                setMinValue(13);
                setMaxValue(23);
                break;
            }
            break;  
        case DATA_MILES_PER_HOUR:
            System.out.println("convertSpeedUnit::formerUnit - DATA_MILES_PER_HOUR");
            switch (newValue){
            case KILO_METERS_PER_HOUR:
                System.out.println("convertSpeedUnit::currentUnit - KILO_METERS_PER_HOUR");
                setMinValue(34);
                setMaxValue(45);
                break;
            case METERS_PER_SECOND:
                System.out.println("convertSpeedUnit::currentUnit - METERS_PER_SECOND");
                setMinValue(56);
                setMaxValue(67);
                break;
            }
            break;
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to [provide code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and complete replication steps for your issue as well as information on your environment (SceneBuilder version).  Are you following the [Oracle guide to Adding Custom Components to the Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/scene-builder-2/user-guide/library-panel.htm#JSBRG181)?

Comment: Hi, I dont have problem with adding custom component into SB. My environment: Product Version : JavaFX Scene Builder 2.u
Java 1.8.0_25-b18, Oracle Corporation
Operating System : Windows 8.1, amd64, 6.3

Comment: Just I am trying to organize an example code to provide here. In short, I could not see the old value of a property of my custom component with SB although it works in demo app.